# ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Google_OAuth2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want sign up with google plus in codeigniter. I have  include files which are required for the php script but I'm getting error

> (( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Google_OAuth2 in
>   D:\wamp\www\Surecash_back\application\libraries\google-plus-api-client-master\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php
>   on line 453)

Comment: You required them?, or did you autoload them?, might be doing both right now

Comment: can you at least show your code here.

Comment: use `include_once()` rather than `include()`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

**The error message tells you a very simple thing:**

You are trying to load\include the same class file more then once
(which results in re-declaring a class name of an already declared class).

The fastest way to check this, will be:

1. If you are using an autoloader - check your autoloader folder tree for the existance of a file named Google_OAuth2.php
2. Run a project-wide (all files in your project) search for the string "Google_OAuth2.php" and another search for "class Google_OAuth2", look for any duplicate *include()*, *include_once()* or *require_once()*.

   *(in phpStorm you click Cmd+Shift+F to open the path search, and in the options tab select "Whole project" in Scope.)*

See where and if you are including\requiring\autoloading the Google_OAuth2 class file more then one time.

Finally, remove the duplicate.

Hope it helps a bit!